# Vector.push_back() adds same Element while reading from File

Tags: c++, file, vector, fopen

My Code is reading a set of Elements from a file and adds those to a Vector.  The for-loop reads all the elements and via push_back they are added to the vector. Works perfectly fine on paper BUT: In the end all the Elements in the Vector are equal and always the last read element.

I am 100 percent certain the Elements listed in the File aren't the same (because of the good old NotePad++). Ive tried to c-out the read in elements to check if there is a problem with the f_read function. The Program outputted the Elements perfectly fine and in the right order. I am guessing the error isn't with the file or the f_read function.

```
FILE* f = fopen(filepath, "rb");
unsigned char header[19];
fread_s(header, sizeof(header), sizeof(unsigned char), 19, f);

vector<char*> myVector;
int size = 28 * 28;
char temp[28 * 28];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    fread_s(temp, 28*28, sizeof(unsigned char), size, f);
    myVector.push_back(temp);
}
```

( the 19 bits i am reading into the "info" char array are the header)

I Expect the Vector to contain all the Read Elements in the right order.

Comment: There is only 1 `temp` array and your `myVector`'s elements all point to the first element of that array.

Comment: Consider using `std::vector<std::string>> myVector;` instead. It will be easier and safer to use.

Comment: `push_back` will copy a **pointer**, not the whole content of the array.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen okay so how would i add not a pointer to the char array but instead the whole content of it?

Comment: @jakob _"okay so how would i add not a pointer to the char array but instead the whole content of it?"_ As mentioned use `std::string` instead of `char*` and `char xx[]`.

Comment: @jakob You have a `vector` of pointers, so that's the only thing you will ever be able to get in there. You need to change the type of your container if you want to store something else.

Comment: Just for future reference, you could have eliminated the file I/O and reproduced this error with two hard-coded strings.

Comment: @Beta Agreed, that doesn't have anything to do with file I/O. OP should use `std::istream` (`std::istringstream` specifically for your proposal) to read the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you are pushing the pointers back not the actual strings. To get the actual strings you can do this:

```
void readFileToVec()
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open ("rb");
    vector<string> v;
    string word;
    while (file >> word)
    {
        v.push_back(word);
    }
}
```

This will work if the elements are all strings and are seperated by a space,tab, or newline. If your words are seperated by anything other than one of these three (for example a list of words separated by commas) then you can use getline and specify the separator.

In any case, reading about C++ streams and the difference between C-style strings and STL strings would be worthwhile if you intend to do this sort of thing with C++ again. You are using C Strings and old school FILE which is part of the C Library while C++ provides you with utilities to make your life easier. File streams and C++ strings are great examples of such utilities.